# (Nobara 39) How to reinstall nvidia drivers from LIVE ISO?

Tags: fedora

I just accidentally removed nvidia drivers and rebooted. Since I previously blacklisted(?) other graphic drivers - I can't log back in. Is there a way to reinstall nvidia (or re-enable the default drivers) from live Nobara ISO?